# iphone dev: how to control the view transition animation?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using such code to present a new view, I don't it's good or not. Currently the default animation is show the view from bottom up, but i want it to animate from right to left(fly in), is it possible to change the default animation type and how? Thanks.

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:animated];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the slide-up animation like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

Then you can provide your own animation code:

```
navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, navController.view.frame.size.width, navController.view.frame.size.height);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, navController.view.frame.size.width, navController.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This example gives you the "Fly-in" from right with a smooth speed-curve.

Another way is using the built in slide-in from right with navigationcontroller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

In this one, your top-viewcontroller needs to be a UINavigationController and it's rootcontroller needs to be your viewcontroller. Then you can push other viewcontrollers.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I am wondering that most of the iphone app using right to left fly in effect, is it a system provided feature?

Comment: It can't work, by changing my code to yours(the last solution), the view just can't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and its working for me try ths:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
            [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.View2.superview cache:YES];
            [self.View2 removeFromSuperview];   
            [self performSelector:@selector(replaceViews2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
```